# (Bootstrap 4) container not responsive for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 on a litte project for school. I created a layout where there's a carousel next to some text. The problem is that my carousel on the right is responsive for every device width except for mobile devices. It's adjusting perfectly on every other device width, but for some reason my carousel is too big for mobile devices.

Every help is appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>deinUrlaub.at</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="imgs/icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mall.css">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md py-4 bg-info navbar-dark">
        <!-- Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="imgs/logoNAV.png" class="float-right rounded-circle" alt="deinUrlaub.at" width="100">
        </a>

        <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Navbar links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link h4 active" href="index.html">START</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link h4" href="TOP-3.html">TOP 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link h4" href="BILDERGALERIE.html">BILDERGALERIE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link h4" href="ÜBER.html">ÜBER</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="p-4 justify-content-center">
        
        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mb-4" >Zurück</a>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="float-right">
                <div class="container ml-2 my-2">
                <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- The slideshow -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="rounded" src="imgs/mallorcaBild1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="800">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="rounded" src="imgs/mallorcabild2.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="800">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="rounded" src="imgs/mallorcabild3.jpg" alt="New York" width="800">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Left and right controls -->
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                </div> 
            </div>
            </div>
            <h1>Mallorca</h1>
            <h2 class="text-secondary">Mallorca bietet wunderschöne Strände mit einem traumhaften türkisen Meer.
            </h2>
            <br>
            <p>Nicht ohne Grund ist Mallorca die beliebteste Baleareninsel, denn sie hält jede Menge für ihre
                Besucher bereit. Egal wie man den Urlaub gestalten möchte, es gibt für jeden Geschmack etwas.
            </p>
                <br>
                <p>
                Strandliebhaber und Sonnenanbeter finden Ihr Glück an langen Stränden oder kleinen Buchten, umspült
                von kristallklarem, azurblauem Wasser und gesäumt meistens mit feinem, weißen Sand. Das Mittelmeer
                bietet aber noch viel mehr – für Wassersportler gibt es Angebote für zum Tauchen und Schnorcheln,
                Segeln, sowie Kayakfahren und viel mehr.
            </p>
            <br>
            <p>
                An Land findet sich ebenso viel zu entdecken, etwa für Wanderer oder Radfahrer. Die einzigartige
                Gebirgslandschaft der Serra de Tramuntana mit ihren pittoresken Bergdörfern laden zu Touren oder
                Ausflügen im Mietwagen ein.

                Wer auf Mallorca Urlaub machen will, wählt aus einer Vielzahl an Unterkünften aus, neben attraktiven
                Hotels mit Poollandschaften, gibt es zudem ländliche Hotels, Apartments, sowie Ferienhäuser oder
                Fincas.</p>
                <div class="text-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-5 mt-4" >Jetzt Buchen</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>


    <footer class="container-fluid p-5 bg-info text-white text-left">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column col-md-11">
                <p>TEL: 0680 3336549</p>
                <p>EMAIL: support.deinUrlaub@gmail.com</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <br>
                <p>&copy; deinUrlaub.at</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

And here's my css:

```
    h1 {
    font-size: 65px;
}
p {
    font-size: 23px;
}  
.btn-sm {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.container {
    width: 50pc;
}
.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: u set fixed width to 50pc which is fixed for all devices, u need to read more about units so u can choose the best unit for your design, px , rem ,em , vh , vw, etc... here is [Units by W3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: You shouldn't be overriding bootstrap defined classes in your custom CSS. This will lead to a lot of problems later on. Also, the CSS unit `pc` is experimental and not a lot of browsers  support it

Comment: It doesn't matter if I use pc or px etc. The problem still remains except for %, this one brings me some kinda weird bar on the far right (next to my carousel on the right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just fixed it by not writing a specific width in .container, but giving it a min-width aswell as a max-width (which would be my specific width). Thanks for helping everyone!

Comment: Hi @Nikiii : Just try .container {
    max-width: 100vw;
}
.carousel-inner img {
    object-fit:cover;                                                                                           
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }